# Sockets c++ , weird issue with recieved info

Tags: c++, sockets, client, system

Well heres the thing : i want to make a remote cmd so whenever im at work i can download files from my home computer , for somereason it doesnt respond the way i want to , when i send the dir command it doesnt even execute the if statement .

Please forgive me if this is obvious Im new to those stuff.

Notes:
Server connects and client prints out the sent buffer.

those are different programs v

Server.cpp

```
#include "FirstTouch.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")

 void SendCommands()
{
while (1)
{
    char SendBuffer[1500];
    cin >> SendBuffer;
    send(sConn, SendBuffer, 1500, 0);

    if (SendBuffer == "dir")
    {
        printf("system_dir initiated\n");
        Sleep(200);
        char File[1500];
        recv(sConn, File, strlen(File), 0);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 9);
        cout << File << endl;
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
        delete File;
    }
}

}


int main()
{

ConnectToServer();
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
printf("connected");
system("cls");
SendCommands();
return 0;

}
```

Client.cpp

```
   #include <winsock.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32")

SOCKET s; //Socket handle

//CONNECTTOHOST – Connects to a remote host
bool ConnectToHost(int PortNo, char* IPAddress)
{
    //Start up Winsock…
    WSADATA wsadata;

    int error = WSAStartup(0x0202, &wsadata);

    //Did something happen?
    if (error)
        return false;

    //Did we get the right Winsock version?
    if(wsadata.wVersion != 0x0202)
    {
        WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
        return false;
    }

    //Fill out the information needed to initialize a socket…
    SOCKADDR_IN target; //Socket address information

    target.sin_family = AF_INET; // address family Internet
    target.sin_port = htons(PortNo); //Port to connect on
    target.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPAddress); //Target IP

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); //Create socket
    if (s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't create the socket
    }

    //Try connecting...

    if (connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&target, sizeof(target)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return false; //Couldn't connect
    }
    else
        return true; //Success
}

//CLOSECONNECTION – shuts down the socket and closes any connection on it
void CloseConnection()
{
    //Close the socket if it exists
    if (s)
        closesocket(s);

    WSACleanup(); //Clean up Winsock
}



int main()
{
    bool Conn = false;
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_GREEN);
    printf("Trying to make a reliable connection to server...");
    while (!Conn)
    {
        Conn = ConnectToHost(444, "127.0.0.1");
    }

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), 5);
    system("cls");
    printf("Connected say hi!\n");
    while (1)
    {

        char RecvBuffer[1500];
        recv(s, RecvBuffer, 1500, 0);
        printf(RecvBuffer);
        std::cout << std::endl;

        if (RecvBuffer == "dir")
        {
            printf("Executing...\n");
            Sleep(100);
            system("dir >> temp.txt");
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("temp.txt", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
            LPVOID FileContent = nullptr;
            LPDWORD NumOfBytes = nullptr;
            ReadFile(hFile, FileContent, 1500, NumOfBytes, NULL);
            CloseHandle(hFile);
            delete[] NumOfBytes;
            send(s, (char*)FileContent, 1500, 0);
            delete FileContent;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from ignoring the result of the recv() call, (as answered by @EJP), the following printf call assumes that RecvBuffer' contains a null-terminated C-string.  That is not a lock.

Comment: ...and, (it seems almost inevitable in network code), misuse of strlen: automatic storage var 'char File[1500];' followed immediately by 'recv(sConn, File, strlen(File), 0);'.

Comment: Approx. 1% of strlen() calls in SO network code questions are valid.

Comment: .. and printf() is not far behind.

Comment: 'delete File;' on automatic-storage var - segfault/UB.

Comment: FileContent is null when passed to ReadFile() - UB/segfault.

Comment: NumOfBytes is passed as nullptr, which is legal but then you have no idea of how many bytes you have read, and so how many to send.

Comment: 'delete[] NumOfBytes;' when NumOfBytes is nullptr - UB/segfault.

Comment: 'delete FileContent;' on undefined, unallocated var.

Comment: No error-checking on system calls.

Comment: Do not call delete, or delete[], on anything that has not been alloctaed with operator new.

Comment: Thanks for the tips mate! fixed alot of problems and explained alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recv() isn't guaranteed to fill the buffer. You have to loop.

Comment: what do you mean? I am in a loop ? or should recieve char by char?
thanks for the reply!

Comment: @GuyI Received message may be a part of the hole message. To get it all, you should use a loop to receive parts on each iteration.